# UWP App and Package in the same Solution - two apps

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to UWP and Package creation, I have followed multiple examples, but can't figure out why this is happening for me.

I have UWP app and a Package that reference UWP app
when I build/debug the solution I get two apps created. Please point me in the right direction!

[image]

Comment: A vanilla UWP typically does not need a separate packaging project created for it, so you should be able to drop the packaging project.

Comment: I do need a packaging project as I have multiple Projects in the solution UWP and non-UWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you enable the deployment and build of the independent uwp app.

If you want to solve this issue, you could only deploy and build the templated project. Please try the following steps to do this.
You could right click the solution and select the option “**Configuration Manager**”, then disenable the **deploy** and **build** of UwpApp.

[image]